# panel & list group dropdown

Tags: asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

[bootstrap panel & list group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0hM1.png)

how can i to make the 'company trip' to stay active when i clicked it. i need JS or Jquery for it i guess. can anyone help me?

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a href="#albums2013" class="list-group-item list-group" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Albums 2013<span class="icon-angle-down pull-right"></span></a>
      </h4>
      <div class="collapse" id="albums2013">
        <a href="2013-company-trip.aspx#Redang" class="list-group-item">Company Trip (Redang)</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your code

```
#albums2013 a:active, #albums2013 a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

you can add your custom style so that it looks active in the above selector.
I hope this helps :)

Comment: i want make the company trip redang keep stay active when i click it. above has the image.

Comment: because whenever i select other category, it will close it. i want it stay open